# Dropdown Menu not working in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

the drop down menu on http://lasvegas.informermg.com/ isnt working correctly. I am able to get it to work when i use Firebug to remove the element.style of visibility: hidden and display:none; then the menu works.

But I can not find in any of the files where to edit it so it stays this way. Tried all the .css files and the .php files

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
```

is what it looks like when not working and when i put

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
```

it works fine. but again i can find where to make that change and set it permanently, since its element.style i dont think it is in the css and i have looked in the header.php but  this is all it has

```
    <div id="menuwrapper">
        <ul class="mainnav dropdown">
            <?php
            if(of_get_option('of_nav1') == 1) { 
                wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'items_wrap' => '%3$s'));
            } else { ?>
                <li <?php if(is_home() ) { ?>class="current-cat first"<?php } ?>><a href="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>"><?php _e('Home','snapwire'); ?></a></li>
                <?php wp_list_categories('orderby='. of_get_option('of_order_cats') .'&order='. of_get_option('of_sort_cats') .'&title_li=&exclude='. of_get_option('of_ex_cats'));
                wp_list_pages('sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&exclude='. of_get_option('of_ex_pages'));
            } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

so again not seeing where to make the change.

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Superfish is supposed to be taking care of showing and hiding the menus, but it's broken (check your console and you'll see it's showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined`).

The reason it's broken is because it relies on jQuery's `$.browser`, which isn't available in jQuery 1.9.0. (By the way, it's also breaking fancyBox for the same reason).

See [this post](http://www.studiopress.com/forums/topic/superfish-broken-with-jquery-1-9/) where someone has the same problem. The fix that's recommended is including [jQuery Migrate](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.min.js).

Another solution is use a lower version of jQuery if you're not relying on 1.9.0 features elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of trial and error I came to the following simple solution:

Disable superfish.js

Add the following styles:

```
.current_page_item  ul {
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}
```